# I've seen 待つ in the te-form as both 待て and 待って; the latter should be correct. Does meaning/pronunciation change and why it would be written this way

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, written-language

My example, as like many of my recent ones is from {{JP:灰と幻想のグリムガル}}, and is as follows:

> {{JP:「・・・・俺も行こっかな」と誰かが。男の声だ。「ま、ま、待てってじゃあオレも！」}}.

The text itself seems simple enough to understand, I think. One person says they'll go too, and the other says "wait, erm, I'll go too." Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong as I really try not to pretend I know what I'm talking about! However, why the use of {{JP:待て}} and not {{JP:待って}}? And I guess as a side note, why add the {{JP:って}} after the first {{JP:待て}} as, from what I know that's usually used to mark the speaker of a quotation, not within the quote itself???

EDIT: I have double and triple-checked the text to make certain this isn't a typo. If someone disagrees I'll be sure to delete the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For verbs that end in つ, the imperative (command) form ends in て. It's just a coincidence that that looks similar to the same verb in て form.

And yes, the pronunciation is not the same, as indicated by the lack of the small つ.

Comment: just FYI, when I mentioned the pronunciation change I was referring to a possible change in the kanji's pronunciation. Regardless, thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: But the meaning seems like the same. They both seem to mean the imperative. [LOL]{citation needed}

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Verbs in the て form with nothing else following them are equivalent to a light request, similar in feeling to saying ～てください, except without the explicitly polite ending. Verbs in imperative form are commands, not requests. You would not be able to soften them with ください or something similar, as it would be ungrammatical. So, while there may be situations where the appropriateness of using one or the other might overlap a bit, they don't actually mean the same thing, and there are certainly cases where one or the other would be completely inappropriate.